# Pseudonymisation within ASP.NET MVC/SQL Azure web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am exploring how I can implement Pseudonymisation within my ASP.NET MVC/ SQL Azure Web Application.

I am struggling how to do this within Azure.

Current thoughts include:

1) Another secure SQL Azure DB with the Personal Data and key

2) Another secure data storage mechanism within Azure for this type of data ie "Azure Key Vault".

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to replace the identifying fields of data records with pseudonyms and securely and separately store correspondence of "identifying fields-pseudonyms" on Azure?

Comment: Hi @FredHan-MSFT, Yes that sounds like what I want to do. Our DB is TDE encrypted at present, but I want to go a step further and remove the names from the client table to remove the "identifiability" of the data, so remove the use of it if someone got their hands on it. Obviously it needs "stitching" together again when the record is retrieved by an authorised application user. Also this approach is recommended within the wording of the GDPR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to implement [Pseudonymisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonymization) for your data records to replace the identifying fields of data records with pseudonyms. As you mentioned ( ***`Another secure SQL Azure DB with the Personal Data and key`*** ), Azure SQL Database can be used to separately store correspondence of "identifying fields-pseudonyms", and [Azure can help keep customer data safe](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/).

Besides, you could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview) that shows the information about securing Azure SQL Database.